# How to persist bookmarklet when loading new url?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm not sure if this is possible~

Say a bookmarklet that creates an embedded iframe loaded with a web application and there's a few urls in the web application. When urls are clicked, they are loaded into the current browser window which is running the bookmarklet. By default, the bookmarklet will be "gone" after that. Is there any way to persist the bookmarklet after the loading?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge this is not possible. If you need to do something like this you need to write a browser plugin/extension.

Comment: it seems so, I've searched around and yet to come across a bookmarklet with similar functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm thinking perhaps introduce a "hidden iframe" to wrap the current web page in the browser then make the urls in the web application to load into the "hidden iframe. In this way, it doesn't trigger the browser and thus persisting the bookmarklet, might work? Guess I got to give it a try soon.

Comment: Hidden iframe doesn't work cross domain. So unless your bookmarklet comes from the same domain as the site in the iframe it won't work.